# Custom xhtml tag to reduce repeated blocks

Tags: xml, xhtml

I have an xhtml file with many `<message>` blocks that are the same except for a single identifier `##IDENTIFIER##` that appears in a few places. Note: `##IDENTIFIER##` is a placeholder for plain-text values that are use in this message block.

```
<message id="##IDENTIFIER##">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
            <div class="box-title">
                <h3 class="box-title-text">Title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
                ${specialblock: "##IDENTIFIER##"}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="edit">
            ${##IDENTIFIER##: "data"}
        </div>
    </div>
</message>
```

What I would like to be able to do is make a custom tag that I could use to replace the above code block with something like: `<mymessage value="##IDENTIFIER##"/>`.

Is this possible to do? If so, what is a good way to do this? I have started looking into schemas and entity references, but I don't quite understand them yet, and I'm not sure if they will even provide the behavior that I am looking for.

EDIT: I would also prefer if this could be done in the same file, but I can add other files if necessary.

Comment: Is `##IDENTIFIER##` an actual string value or is it a placeholder of some kind? Also, can you use XSLT (to transform the XML)?

Comment: I was just using `##IDENTIFIER##` as a placeholder. I think there wouldn't be a problem with XSLT, is there any documentation you would recommend for that?

Comment: Look at react.js

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to be able to do is make a custom tag that I could use to replace the above code block with something like:

```
<mymessage value="##IDENTIFIER##"/>
```

You can do this with XSLT (version 1.0 suffices). Feed the XML as input to the stylesheet to transform it to the desired output.

For example, if you have some XML (e.g. named `a.xml`) like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <message id="##IDENTIFIER003##">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
                <div class="box-title">
                    <h3 class="box-title-text">Title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                    ${specialblock: "##IDENTIFIER##"}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="edit">
                ${##IDENTIFIER##: "data"}
            </div>
        </div>
    </message>
    <message id="##IDENTIFIER001##">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
                <div class="box-title">
                    <h3 class="box-title-text">Title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                    ${specialblock: "##IDENTIFIER##"}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="edit">
                ${##IDENTIFIER##: "data"}
            </div>
        </div>
    </message>
    <message id="##IDENTIFIER002##">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
                <div class="box-title">
                    <h3 class="box-title-text">Title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                    ${specialblock: "##IDENTIFIER##"}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="edit">
                ${##IDENTIFIER##: "data"}
            </div>
        </div>
    </message>    
</root>
```

applying the following XSLT (e.g. named `a.xslt`)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="message">
    <mymessage value="{@id}" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

would result in this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <mymessage value="##IDENTIFIER003##"/>
    <mymessage value="##IDENTIFIER001##"/>
    <mymessage value="##IDENTIFIER002##"/>        
</root>
```

You can use any XSLT processor for this task.
For example, in Linux you can use `xsltproc` like this

```
xsltproc a.xslt a.xml
```

For Windows there are also plenty of XSLT processors, just google it.